# How can I render newline escape sequences in xargs?

Tags: bash, xargs, echo, newlines

The following command prints 3 lines:

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc'
```

result:

```
a  
b  
c
```

How can I **achieve the above result** when passing from `xargs`?

```
echo 'a\nb\nc' | xargs -I{} echo -e {}
```

Current result:

```
anbnc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer: ( Posted by a user and then removed)

Use a delimiter (`-d`)

```
echo 'a\nb\nc' | xargs -d '\n' -I{} echo -e {}
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `\` to explicit the use of `\n`:

```bsh
echo 'a\\nb\\nc' | xargs -I{} echo -e {}
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried correcting

```
echo 'a\n\b\n\c'
```

to

```
echo 'a\nb\nc'
```

The output is on different lines then. Is that what you want?

Comment: the command as it is in your question is generating the expected output in my sh. Is it still anbnc for you?